# How can the wife of a UK expat get a an A10 residency card to visit the UK

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I'm a UK citizen, who currently resides in Ecuador, with my bolvian wife and dual nationality kids.

We want to visit Europe this summer.

As I understand it, if my wife holds an A10 residency card, she can enter the uk.

I'm not clear on *how to get one of these cards?* We're planning on flying into Madrid. Am I right in thinking that when we arrive, if we have a marriage certificate, that they must provide my wife with the residency card?

If not can we get one? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Your wife can get an article ten card from Spain if she resides with you in Spain, or from any EU or EEA country if she resides with you in that country.  Since you do not reside in the EU or EEA, your wife cannot get an article ten card, and she therefore needs a visa to visit the UK.